# How many vertices for non-isomorphic graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

I started drawing planar, cubic, bipartite graphs consisting of faces with $4$ or $6$ vertices only. I found that six $4$-faces are sufficient to do that. The smallest graph is a planar drawing of the cube.

How many vertices or $6$-faces are necessary to get two non-isomorphic graphs?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Are you asking for the smallest (in terms of vertices) pair of planar cubic graphs with 6-sided faces?

Comment: @gilleain yes; 6 4-sided and x 6-sided faces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the outer face must have length 4 or 6, it should be possible to prove your graphs must be at least 3-connected. But then your graphs are examples of [Barnette graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnette%27s_conjecture) (cubic bipartite 3-connected planar graphs) which are conjectured to all have Hamiltonian cycles.

These have been studied fairly extensively, and you can find a drawings of all the Barnette graphs on up to 20 vertices in Appendix A [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/files/6313/5795/0203/DeLaTorreThesis.pdf). Browsing through that appendix, it seems there is exactly 1 of your graphs on 8, 12, 14, 16, and 18 vertices (0, 2, 3, 4, and 5 6-faces), no such graph on 10 vertices, and there are 3 non-isomorphic such graphs on 20 vertices (20-3, 20-5, and 20-8 in the Appendix).